# Can't send invitation using linkedin-j library

Tags: android, api, linkedin-api, invitation

I am trying to send Linkedin Invitation from Android app. (I am having all permissions including `Send invitation` or `Message(w_message)`). I can send message successfully but I can't send Invitation.

I am preparing `CommunicationsApiClient` object named `com_cliClient` and tried to send the invitation either by Person or by Id.. **I am not getting any error** in calling below methods but the invitation is not being sent.

Some piece of code:

```
com_cliClient.sendInviteToPerson(p2, "hello", "Invitation...");
com_cliClient.sendInviteById(id, "hello","Invitation",authHeader);
```

I am using `linkedin-j-android.jar` for Android Application.

Comment: did you get any solution? me too facing same issue , but in objective c. If you can't add comments, rather post your response as an answer if it got solved.

Comment: Hello MicRO, I have found the solution..I did not have any problem in coding..But the actual problem is that the Recipient to which I am sending the Invitation have already rejected my invitation earlier once..So it is the Rule or Restriction in Linkedin itself,That you can not send invitation to a person who have rejected it before..Please confirm that You are not sending the invitation to such person..

Comment: Greatt thanks for your reply, anyway I too managed to get rid of this, the issue was something regarding the xml format in my case..

Comment: Hello Mr. Parikh
What is authHeader, can you give an example ?

Comment: Hello aditi, i am using this code  client.sendInviteById(pp.getId(), "hello", "Invitation", toekn.toString()); for send Invitation but this is not working. please can you tell me what is "authHeader" here which u are using